# "None" cannot be compared with numbers. Any other alternatives?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numbers, int, nonetype

In Python 2, you could compare None with integers and floating point numbers in solutions as finding the smallest number by comparing. But in Python 3 they are not able to be compared. Do you have any alternative keywords or solutions for this in Python 3?

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

This is my code:

```py
l = None
s = None

while True:
    n = input("Enter a number: ")
    if (n == "done") :
        break
    try:
        num = int(n)
    except:
        print ("Invalid input")
        continue
    if (s is None):
        s = num
    if (num > l) :
        l = num
    elif (num < s) :
        s = num

def done(l,s):
    print ("Maximum is", l)
    print ("Minimum is", s)

done(l,s)
```

Comment: Depends on the context. Usually you just put a `value is[ not] None` somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Since `None` effectively acted as negative infinity[*] in Python 2, you can use (in place of `x < y`)

```
False if y is None else True if x is None else x < y
```

We check `y` first so that the result is `False` when both `x` and `y` are `None`:

```
>>> def f(x, y):
...   return False if y is None else True if x is None else x < y
...
>>> f(None, None)
False
>>> f(None, -10000)
True
>>> f(-10000, None)
False
```

If you would be defining a function, you should write it using `if` statements for clarity, though:

```
def f(x, y):
    if y is None:
        return False
    if x is None:
        return True
    return x < y
```

---

[*] More precisely, `None` acted as bottom for the lattice implied by `<=`.

Comment: A bit simpler: `y is not None and (x is None or x < y)`.

Comment: Shorter, but in this case I'd like to keep the number of different operators involved to a minimum.

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional (tertiary) operator, ie. instead of:

```
if x > y:
```

use:

```
if (0 if x is None else x) > (0 if y is None else y):
```

Comment: A bit simpler: `(x or 0) > (y or 0)`.

Comment: It works if the desired behaviour is to treat `None` like 0, although that is not Python 2's behaviour. I guess it depends on the use-case.

Answer (score 0):

In those fields where you allow the None type you could first check whether the variable is of type none and, if it does not fulfil the condition, proceed checking with the integer number:

```
if x is not None:
    if x > y:
        # proceed with the operations
```

Answer (score 0):

You filter out the None values before comparing, see if this helps :

```
>>> l = [None, 2,3,5, None, 10]
>>> for i in l:
...       if i is not None:
...             print(i>5)
...       else:
...             print(None)
...
None
False
False
False
None
True
```

***Addition***

```
l = None
s = None

def isNone(a):
    if a is not None:
        return True
    else:
        return False

while True:
    n = input("Enter a number: ")
    if (n == "done") :
        break
    try:
        num = int(n)
    except:
        print ("Invalid input")
        continue
    if (s is None):
        s = num
    if isNone(l):
        if (num > l) :
            l = num
    elif (num < s) :
        s = num

def done(l,s):
    print ("Maximum is", l)
    print ("Minimum is", s)

done(l,s)
```

Since the function of the code is pretty vague, please see if this helps, where you are just checking out whether the element is `None` or not, if not then the it will for the condition check.

Comment: I have added something, please check!